# shell sed get file path

Tags: bash, shell

I have a file path.

```
/ifshk5/BC_IP/PROJECT/T11073/T11073_RICekkR/Fq/AS34_59329/111220_I631_FCC0E5EACXX_L4_RICwdsRSYHSD11-2-IPAAPEK-93_1.fq.gz
```

I want to get this part

```
/T11073_RICekkR/Fq/AS34_59329
```

as `$location`.

How can I use `sed` to get those?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When working with file paths, I find it easier using `awk` - but you can make your own mind up. Here's what I'd do:

```
location=$(echo "$path" | awk -F "/" '{ print "", $6, $7, $8 }' OFS="/")
```

If you're trying to match on a pattern, then `sed` would be a good option. But you haven't mentioned any specifications.

Answer (score 1):

Use `cut` or `awk` (as suggested).

But to do it with `sed` you do something like this:

```
locationpath=/ifshk5/BC_IP/PROJECT/T11073/T11073_RICekkR/Fq/AS34_59329/111220_I631_FCC0E5EACXX_L4_RICwdsRSYHSD11-2-IPAAPEK-93_1.fq.gz
location=$(echo $locationpath | sed 's%\(/[^/]*\)\{4\}\(/[^/]*/[^/]*/[^/]*\).*%\2%')
```